# Is there a way to force all http traffic to Apache to prevent direct access to a web app?

Tags: apache, proxypass

My web app runs and listens on port 8080 using its on mini server. The Apache VirtualHost redirects all :80 traffic to :8080. What I would like to do is block requests directly to localhost (e.g. 127.0.0.1). Is there a way to force all requests on the server thru the Apache instance on that server? Or do I need to do this in .htaccess at the application level.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName mydomain.com
   #ServerAlias anothercooldomain.org

   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyRequests Off
   <Proxy *>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Proxy>
   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/myapp-error.log
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/myapp-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for here. Are you trying to stop all traffic to port 8080, except from Apache, even if the request comes from the same computer? Are you trying to stop all traffic to port 8080 except traffic from a different computer? Are you trying to stop all traffic to port 80 except that with `Host: mydomain.com`?

Comment: "stop all traffic to port 8080, except from Apache, even if the request comes from the same computer"

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's impossible